# Stop program until user clicks button

Tags: jframe, containers

In my main program, I create a JFrame with a button on it. This acts as a separate dialog box that prompts the user for information. What I would like, is when the dialog box appears, is for the program to stop running until the user clicks the button.

If I just create the JFrame normally, the program will move on in the code and do other statements before information is received from the dialog box. This is an issue, because later on in the code another JFrame is created using information from the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate out the logic of displaying the frame from actions that happen after the button is pushed. What I mean is you should add an Action Listener to the Button you have, and put the code inside the its method instead of the main program. The problem is you are visualizing the solution in a procedural oriented way. Think Object Oriented.

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't know why I was trying to make this complicated. That's such a simple solution.

Comment: you could +1 the answer if that helped :)

Comment: I can't, actually. It doesn't let me because I don't have 15 reputation. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Troncoso - You can +1 him now you have 37 rep :).